# Did Ubuntu patch the vulnerable samba version?

Tags: samba, security

In this [article](http://thehackernews.com/2017/05/samba-rce-exploit.html) they said that a vulnerability has been discovered in `samba`.

In this same article, they said that the maintainer of `samba` had already patched the vulnerability in the versions `4.6.4/4.5.10/4.4.14`. And they also said in the article that Ubuntu and Redhat has already released patched versions.

The problem is : the samba version that is installed on my Ubuntu 17.04 is `4.5.8` (I used the command `samba --version` to get this information).

So did Ubuntu release a patched version of `samba` ? and if yes, how does it come that I have the version `4.5.8` and not the `4.5.10` which is patched.

PS : I updated my computer today with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: You say in paragraph 3 that you have version `5.4.8`, but then you say in the next paragraph that you have version `4.5.8`.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I will fix it now

Comment: What version number does `dpkg -l samba` show?

Comment: @jwodder it shows `2:4.5.8+dfsg-0ubun`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu released security updates for this on 2017-05-24, see [Ubuntu Security Notice USN-3296-1](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3296-1/).

As usually Ubuntu doesn't provide the new upstream version but patched the versions for all the supported releases to keep the changes at a minimum.